Derivation of the Vector-Valued Martingale in Bandit Problems
I've been studying a paper (Online Least Squares Estimation with Self-Normalized Processes: An Application to Bandit Problems) on the vector-valued martingale tail inequalities in bandit problems. However, the author does not offer the proof of Theorem 2. Instead, he refers the readers to another paper (Linearly Parameterized Bandits). After checking, I still have little clue how to prove this theorem.
Theorem 2. Consider the processes ($S_t$), ($\bar{V_t}$) as defined above and let $$κ = \sqrt{3+2\log((L^2+trace(V))/λ_0)}$$ Then, for any $0 < δ < 1$, $t ≥ 2$, with probability at least $1−δ$, $$\|S_t\|_{\bar{V_t^{-1}}} ≤ 2 κ^2 R \sqrt{\log(t)} \sqrt{d\log(t) + \log(1/δ)}$$
Let $(F_k;k\ge 0)$ be a filtration, $(m_k;k\ge 0)$ be an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued stochastic process adapted to $(F_k)$, $(\eta_k;k\ge 1)$ be a real-valued martingale difference process adapted to $(F_k)$.
Assume that $\eta_k$ is conditionally sub-Gaussian in the sense that there exists some $R>0$ such that for any $\gamma\in \mathbb{R}$, $k\ge 1$,
$$
\mathbb{E}[ \exp(\gamma \eta_k ) \,|\, F_{k-1} ] \le \exp\left( \frac{\gamma^2 R^2}{2}\right) \quad \mathrm{a.s.}
$$
Consider the martingale
$$
S_t  = \sum_{k=1}^t \eta_k m_{k-1}
$$
and the matrix-valued processes
$$
V_t = \sum_{k=1}^t m_{k-1}m_{k-1}^T, \bar{V_t} = V + V_t, \quad t\ge 0
$$
where $V$ is an $F_{0}$-measurable, positive definite matrix. In particular, assume that with probability one, the eigenvalues of $V$ are larger than $\lambda_0>0$ and that $\|m_k\|\le L$ holds a.s. for any $k\ge 0$.
We use $\|\cdot\|$ to denote the 2-norm. For a positive definite matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, the weighted $2$-norm is defined by $\|x\|^2_A = x^T A x$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$. The inner product is denoted by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and the weighted inner-product $x^T A y = \langle x, y \rangle_{A}$.
We use $\lambda_{\min}(A)$ to denote the minimum eigenvalue of the positive definite matrix $A$.
We use $A\succ 0$ to denote that $A$ is positive definite, while we use $A\succeq 0$ to denote that it is positive semidefinite. The same notation is used to denote the Loewner partial order of matrices.
We shall use  $\textbf{e}_i$ to denote the $i^{\rm th}$ unit vector, i.e., for all $j\neq i $, $\textbf{e}_{ij}=0$ and $\textbf{e}_{ii}=1$.
I need a more detailed answer hopefully step by step, thanks!

Not sure why this is downvoted, although you can definitely clean up the presentation a bit. In any case, note that Theorem 2 is not Abbasi-Yadikori et al's result, its due to Rusmevichientong and Tsitsiklis, which is the paper they've cited. Further, Theorem 3 is an improvement of this result - compare remark 5 on page 6 with Thm 2. In any case, if you want to read a proof of Theorem 2, check out appendix B here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.3465

@stochasticboy321 I thought it was Lemma B.4, but I still failed to proceed.

I mean, this is not really the forum for me to explain the paper to you - if you have specific questions about the arguments, you should ask them, but "prove this theorem", when there are sources for the same already, is not really a good fit for math.SE.

@stochasticboy321 Thanks all the same. I attempted to reach the authors but got no further replies... I have been investigating it for a few weeks but could not deduce Theorem 2 yet.

I suppose maybe the trouble is that the PEGE paper is just analysing the regret, and they don't separately state any version of Theorem 2, although from the confidence ellipsoid they employ, they implicitly must prove the same under the hood. You'll have to break the argument down enough for you to see this, maybe doing this with a friend in person would work. In any case - I think you can use Thm 3 of the OFUL paper to prove thm 2, since the bound there is stronger than that of thm 2, as per remark 5. Did you try that?

Hmm...I still cannot figure it out.
